# How to plot two lines in one graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, linegraph

suppose i have X={0,5.4,6.18,6.81,6.85,6.95,6.96,7.20,7.51} and

Y={0,4.84,5.52,6.00,6.12,6.21,6.23,6.34,6.61}.please help me to plot two lines

with these points in one single graph using MATLAB.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do:

```
x_axis_X = 1:length(X);
y_axis_Y = 1:length(Y);

figure;plot(x_axis_X, X,'o-', y_axis_Y, Y, 'x-');
```

Comment: thanks a lot...but i want to denote the points also in each line..how to do this?

Answer (score 7):

It's confusing that you've called these `X` and `Y`.  Assuming that they are actually two lines with linearly-increasing x-coordinates, you have some options.  The simple way is to use `hold`:

```
plot(X);
hold on;
plot(Y);
hold off;
```

The other way is to combine them into a matrix.  Provided they are the same length (and assuming column vectors):

```
plot( [X Y] );
```

But more fundamentally, you have shown your data as a cell array instead of a vector.  You should convert these to vectors first.  You can use `cell2mat` for this:

```
Xv = cell2mat(X)';
Yv = cell2mat(Y)';
plot( [Xv Yv] );
```

Comment: thanks but i want those points to be marked in different colour..how to do this.thanks

Comment: points should me marked and the lines should be in differnt colour..how can i do this?

Comment: plot(X);
hold on;
plot(Y);
hold off;                                                                                 this program is working for me but i want those points to be marked in different colour and lines should be in differnt colour.thanks

Comment: You will need to read up on the plot function: `help plot` or `doc plot`.  To use the plot colours, you'll have to use my first method where you plot one line at a time.  If that's not powerful enough for you, you will need to modify the colours inside the figure, which is beyond the scope of this particular question.

Answer (score 1):

```
plot(x1, y1, x2, y2, ... xn, yn)
```

You can use plot() like so to put as many x/y coord pairs into a single plot simultaneously.